# MySQL cumulative total by month

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sum `totalSales` based on the `month` selected, i.e if March is selected then sum `totalSales` from January to March

Sales table

| id | month | year | totalSales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | January | 2019 | 150000 |
| 2 | February | 2019 | 120000 |
| 3 | March | 2019 | 80000 |
| 4 | April | 2019 | 200000 |
| 5 | May | 2019 | 400000 |

Comment: You can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71421721/bigquery-sum-previous-days-value/71422115#71422115

Comment: Hopefully you'll get an idea. but you've to use mysql 8.0

Comment: Is the `month` column really a string?

Comment: @kmoser yes it is

Comment: You'll have to incorporate something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/15708583/378779 (or create a table that maps month names to numbers) in order to determine the month order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT month, year,
    SUM(totalSales) OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY FIELD(month, 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')) AS totalSales
        ) temp
    WHERE year=2021 AND month='May'
```